# Overriding event handler in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a form with a custom control in it. That control has an event handler on the ItemChanged event.

```
private void ncNomSimple_ItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    some code..
}
```

I inherit this form, thus I have the control and the event in my new form but I want another event handler in my new form to be called for that event, not the above one.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: what's the event handler you want to call from ncNomSimple_ItemChanged?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the base class:

```
protected virtual void ncNomSimple_ItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("called from Test class");
}
```

In the derived class:

```
protected override void ncNomSimple_ItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("called from Test1 class");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the event handler from `private` to `protected virtual` and override it in the inherited form.

Answer (score 0):

in the base class, write it as （public/protected）virtual, then you can write the override in the child class, but i do not think base class should be protected. correct me if i wrong

Comment: You're wrong. It makes no sense (and is a syntax error) to have `private virtual` as private members are hidden from derived classes.